# Angular 9 (without Ivy) how to get _view from ViewContainerRef?

Tags: angular, angular9, angular-ivy

I've a project (that was working a few days ago) that uses angular 9 without Ivy

tsconfig

```
{
    "angularCompilerOptions": {
        "enableIvy": false,
    },
"compilerOptions": {
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "target": "es2015",
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "Node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "lib": [
            "es2018",
            "dom"
        ],
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "types": [
            "node"
        ],
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types"
        ]
    },
    
}
```

My directive

```
export class SomeDirective {


    constructor(viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {
        this.workspace = (viewContainerRef as any)._view.component;
    }
    
}
```

For some reason (probably on classpath), I got and error when I try to get the viewContainerRef._view.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'component' of undefined
    at new SomeDirectiveDirective (someDirective.directive.ts:18)
    at NodeInjectorFactory.SomeDirectiveDirective_Factory [as factory] (ɵfac.js? [sm]:1)
    at getNodeInjectable (core.js:5993)
    at instantiateAllDirectives (core.js:12997)
    at createDirectivesInstances (core.js:12209)
    at ɵɵelementStart (core.js:21302)
    at WorkspaceComponent_Template (template.html:1)
    at executeTemplate (core.js:12169)
```

When I debug it I see that viewContainerRef doesn't contain *_view* but instead *_hostView*.

Where the values _view and _hostView comes from?
It's related with the Ivy compiler? If so, it means that my "angularCompilerOptions" is being ignored, right?

```
ng version 

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/
    

Angular CLI: 9.1.15
Node: 12.3.1
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 9.1.13
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... platform-server, router
Ivy Workspace: No

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.901.15
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.901.15
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.901.15
@angular-devkit/core              9.1.15
@angular-devkit/schematics        9.1.15
@angular/cdk                      9.2.4
@angular/cli                      9.1.15
@angular/material                 9.2.4
@ngtools/webpack                  9.1.15
@schematics/angular               9.1.15
@schematics/update                0.901.15
rxjs                              6.6.7
typescript                        3.8.3
webpack                           4.46.0
```

PS- Is this information enough?
Edit - Added the compiler options